# Hi guys, I am working on my project mediaqueries' and was wondering if it's possible to make draggable tab menu using only Css

Tags: css

I want it to look a little like this. So that the users can just drag the screen to switch between tabs.

[image]

Comment: Drag gesture ? I'm afraid you'll need Javascript. If you just want 'tabs', you could do with just CSS using something like `input[type="radio"]:checked + div { display: block }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty close without using javascript (progressive enhancement)

The main trick is to use [scroll-snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type)

Run code snippet below to see a demo or visit this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/KKvjaBq)

```js
// a bit of progressive enhancement

// DOM elements
const page = document.querySelector('.page')
const articles = [...document.querySelectorAll('article')]

// intersection observer to watch when an article is in view 
// using threshold .5 will report isIntersecting on the  
// article that is most in view (50%+)   
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        // get the id of the intersecting article
        // and add it as a data attribute on the 
        // page element (could be a class or whatever)
        const id = entry.target.id
        page.dataset.tabSelected = id
      }
    })
  }, {
    threshold: .5
  }
);

articles.forEach(el => observer.observe(el))
```

```css
/* minimal css reset */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

main {
  /* place articles side by side  */
  display: flex;

  /* allow horizontal scrolling */
  overflow-x: auto;

  /* smooth scrolling when using nav links to navigate */
  scroll-behavior: smooth;

  /* snap items when scrolling horizontally */
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;

  /* full page height minus navigation */
  height: calc(100vh - 4rem);

  /*  hide scrollbars firefox + ie */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}


/*  hide scrollbars chrome */
main::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


/* iOS flex hack to allow right margin 
   after last article element   
*/
main::after {
    content: '';
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: .1px;
}



article {
  /* use center as snap point */
  scroll-snap-align: center;

  /* 
    prevent shrink to allow full width 
    and cause scrolling on main container
    */
  flex-shrink: 0;

  /* full width and height (minus a bit of margin) */
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  height: calc(100% - 2rem);
  margin: 1rem;

  /* scroll overflowing content  */
  overflow-y: auto;
}



/* progressive enhancement (javascript) 
   set navigation tab style 
*/
[data-tab-selected="tab1"] [href="#tab1"],
[data-tab-selected="tab2"] [href="#tab2"],
[data-tab-selected="tab3"] [href="#tab3"]{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .7);
    color: #095d55; 
} 



/* just some styling */
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
    height: 4rem; 
    background-color: #095d55;  
}

nav a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem; 
    border-radius: 2rem;
    transition: 
        color 600ms,
        background-color 600ms
        ;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;   
}

main {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

article {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

  <!-- navigation using in page achors -->
  <nav>
    <a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
    <a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    <a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </nav>

  <!-- main content -->
  <main>
    <!-- content targeted by link 1 -->
    <article id="tab1">
      <h2>Tab 1</h2>
    </article>

    <!-- content targeted by link 2 -->
    <article id="tab2">
      <h2>Tab 2</h2>
    </article>

    <!-- content targeted by link 3 -->
    <article id="tab3">
      <h2>Tab 3</h2>
    </article>
  </main>
</div>
```

PS. if you need drag scroll for desktop users without track mouse
you could [take a look here](https://htmldom.dev/drag-to-scroll/) (just a quick google)

Comment: Cool, I run it in the mobile version and it looks very good. but the scrollbar is being displayed, is there a way to make it invisible while conserving the scrolling?

Comment: What mobile device are you using? - This is just a starter idea – there are a ton of hacks that needs to be considered when it comes to mobile (especially iOS is horrible ;-)

Comment: Well, I didn't check the mobile version, it's not an IOS. I used Firefox(on my windows computer) to run it. Is that IOS that terrible?

Comment: Using the dev tools is a good way to get started - but you should always test on a real mobile device as emulators won't always show how it works in real life. Eg. when seen in FF on a Mac smooth scroll works - on iPhones it won't (there is also "the notch" and annoying 100vh behavior, minimal UI shift, etc.). Making an app-like experience is challenging but also fun – you get a lot of how-do-i-fix-this and a lot of victories when you do :-)

Comment: The challenge is somewhat frustrating but fun indeed. i will do so, thank you